# Button's command is being called when the code starts, not when I press the button

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I wanted to make button in tkinter, but when I started program, the command always calls when code just starts.
Here is example code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("pls work")
window.wm_geometry("100x100")

def message():
    messagebox.showinfo("Hi there")

button = tk.Button(text="Hello", command=message())
button.grid(column=0, row=0)

while True:
    window.update()
```

After, button doesn't work anymore.

**I don't know what I'm doing wrong, so I need help.**

Comment: you need to pass function as command not the return value.  *command=message*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command should be a pointer to a function

In the code you wrote, the command gets the return value from the function.

```
command=message()
```

The correct way is

```
command = message
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are requesting a return value from the fucnction. Try using this.

```
from tkinter import *

# import messagebox from tkinter module
import tkinter.messagebox

# create a tkinter root window
root = tkinter.Tk()

# root window title and dimension
root.title("When you press a button the message will pop up")
root.geometry('75x50')

# Create a messagebox showinfo

def onClick(): 
   tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Hello World!.",  "Hi I'm your message")

# Create a Button
button = Button(root, text="Click Me", command=onClick, height=5, width=10)

 # Set the position of button on the top of window.
 button.pack(side='top')
 root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors:

first:
It must be `command=message`

second:
You must give a message argument too, you entered a title only.

Answer (score 0):

Or, what you can do is.
Add another variable.

```
command = message()
```

Before this line,

```
button = tk.Button(text="Hello", command=message())
```

And chande this line to,

```
button = tk.Button(text="Hello", command=command)
```

Comment: What is the need for another variable when you can directly call `message`

Comment: I know there is no need, but for if any reason it does not work. You can try this alternative.